# Unable to run any workflow on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have several workflows on various lists of my SharePoint online site, which are set to fire off on item creation, edit or manually. Recently, the workflows don't start on any of them and I get the following error message:

> ```
>   Suspend this workflow
> ```
>
> Activity in progress
>
> last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/_api/sp.utilities.utility.ResolvePrincipalInCurrentcontext?input=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cfirst.last%40xxxxxx.in%27&scopes=%2715%27&sources=%2715%27&inputIsEmailOnly=%27false%27&addToUserInfoList=%27False%27&matchUserInfoList=%27true%27 Correlation Id: a2274fcf-2515-2bd7-925c-f7c37b6f377a Instance Id: 878f5590-4c90-49ec-ad5d-e2bdeea1d06b 
>   Retry now

I have full administration permission (Full Control) and am also a global admin for this tenant. Until 1-2 days back, I was able to run all workflows normally. Any thoughts?

---

Update 19 March:
After doing several tests, the problem has been isolated. The issue is that no actions are working within the app step. It also seems that the Workflow app has lost all permissions to perform any actions on the entire Office 365 tenant.

The workflow app has already been provided 'full control' earlier and all the workflows were working fine until few days back.

Comment: If you have not made any changes to the workflows or permissions, then you need to make a support request to Office 365.  One possible cause is that a SharePoint 2010 style workflow with an Impersonation Step was created by a user who has been deleted or had their permissions changed.

Comment: Just updated the problem based on new tests conducted.

Comment: did you change any column/site column?

Comment: Nothing was changed